# SDE similar to Ornstein-Uhlenbeck but with monic drift

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

The Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process has the form
$$d X_{t}=-\kappa X_t d t+\sigma d W_{t}$$
for $\kappa$ and $\sigma >0$, 
has the solution $X_t$ is normal with parameters
\begin{aligned}
&E[X(t)]=e^{-\kappa\left(t-t_{0}\right)} E\left[x_{0}\right]\\
&\operatorname{Var}[X(t)]=\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2 \kappa}\left(1-e^{-2 \kappa\left(t-t_{0}\right)}\right)+e^{-2 \kappa\left(t-t_{0}\right)} \operatorname{Var}\left[x_{0}\right]
\end{aligned}

I would like to know how a process of the form
$$d X_{t}=-\kappa X_t^n d t+\sigma d W_{t}$$
for $n\in \mathbb N$ can be solved. Do these processes have a name`?

I can tell what the stationary distribution of such processes look like, since they need to solve the Fokker Plank equation, but not the solution.